# Get the mic volume and display the value on a gauge

Tags: ios, audio

I want to create an application for measuring the sound input on an iPad.

Users will have to scream into the iPad mic and a gauge will display the scream level. So I will have to get the mic volume and display the value on the gauge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AVAudioRecorder` for that. Have a look at this tutorial: [Tutorial: Detecting When A User Blows Into The Mic](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/)

In [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html), focus on:

**Using Audio Level Metering**

- `meteringEnabled`  property
- `updateMeters`
- `peakPowerForChannel:`
- `averagePowerForChannel:`

Comment: This will only give you the average values for one second. Fine for this application, I suppose.

Comment: @Totoro I am getting same values and the values are not changing even though I am calling update meters.